Consequences of my actions or Gd?
Let’s say I eat a ton of chocolate and get a big stomach ache, should I think that I got the stomach ache because I was stupid and ate all that food, or should I think that God gave me that stomach ache?

Why set this up as a binary?

How about "God gave you stomach ache because you were acting stupid"?

God rules thru nature, you got a stomach ache for eating the chocolate as a direct result, not a specific punishment. Then Hashem will punish you again at a later time for being a fool, glutton, and harming your body

Last Mishna of Berachot:

חיב אדם לברך על הרעה כשם שהוא מברך על הטובה... בכל מדה ומדה שהוא מודד לך הוי מודה לו במאד מאד
Man is obligated to bless Hashem for the bad that happens to him just as much as the good... For each and every last measure Hashem metes out to you, be exceedingly exceedingly grateful.

Everything is from Hashem.
See Tanya, Iggeret Hakodesh 25, based on the Baal Shem Tov's teachings, which explains how if a person does something wrong, and suffers as a result, the person is indeed punished, but that is not to say that the suffering was not decreed from heaven. If he had not done anything wrong, he would have suffered some other way.
See also Chulin 7b as a common reference in the Oral Torah, and for the Written Torah Mishlei 20:24:

A man's steps are from the Lord, for man understands nothing of his way.


הכול בידי שמיים חוץ מצינים פחים

But if I sin I can’t say it was Gd who made me do it (or can I?). So why is this case different. I know this is part of a broader discussion of free will but I was just narrowing in on this one case

@CuriousYid as you can imagine, this is discussed and debated extensively. The way many hold is that the only thing the person actually did was decide to eat the box of chocolates and Hashem caused it to happen, as well as the consequences. They would say yes, God, the only source and cause, gave them a stomach ache. Another important nekuda is that God is the only God, and Ein Od Milvado. Where else are happenings going to come from?

See also Chovos Halevavos, Shaar Habitachon, on what happens if someone does something destructive to himself.

@MichoelR which section are you specifically referring to there?

@RabbiKaii https://www.sefaria.org/Duties_of_the_Heart%2C_Fourth_Treatise_on_Trust.4.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en and read on.

This is posterior apologetics. You can apply the same logic to Miztvos also - if you, say, learned Torah and received a reward, posteriorly it must have been decided for you in Heavens.
Interestingly, you present only one view while you know that the Talmudic tradition holds it at both ends. Why is that?

@AlBerko the answer to that is rather complicated, but off topic. Either way, it is allow on this site to bring legitimate, if controversial, views, so I don't think anything is wrong with what I've done. FWIW, I am a big Eilu v'Eilu guy, and feel contradictions in hashkafa aren't usually impossible to resolve. Also, I notice that essays tend to attract very little reception, but short to the point answers serve the public here better

You are absolutely right. However, my concern is with "לפני עוור" - some, especially newcomers, might see an example as representative of Judaism.

@AlBerko you rock. I don't think it is לפני עוור, but I take that seriously. Also, see this comment and that question at large

This is exactly how I started as a fresh BT thinking that Judaism is monolithic and one opinion covers them all. It took too much time to be greatly disappointed. I would like to save others from that mistake.

The answer of Rabbi Kaii is missing an additional point: we live in the world created by G-d, which follows His laws. Eating too much chocolate violates His laws of following balanced diet. The fact that one gets stomach ache is not a punishment, but a warning built into Creation of an irreparable body failure due to lack of proper nutrients if such behavior continues. Therefore, (I should quote R. Kaii's answer)...

Feel free to edit my answer instead

"His laws of following balanced diet", is it a new tractate I was missing?

@AlBerko https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Human_Dispositions. its a tractate in the 14 volume mishna not the 6 volume

@Mordechai Rambam exploited his authority to add his own views, just like https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.3.1?lang=he So my objection is to "His laws". God did not elaborate on a "balanced diet".

@AlBerko we could interpret the rules of balanced diet from the usage of words with the root חסר - "lacking" in various blessings after meals. We have to consume what the body needs, not what is tasty. That's what "balanced" means.  The 1st blessing is from Moshe.

You're bluffing. Until recently, only the aristocracy could afford to vary their diet, the rest 99% ate whatever they could lay their hands on. You seem to have such a wild imagination to apologize for whatever rabbinic statement you find truthful.

@AlBerko Moshe ate manna which provided perfect nutrition, didn't he? When Jews settled with Yehoshua in Eretz Israel it was flowing with milk and honey, didn't it? The Jewish society lacked any aristcracy since every one had the same legal responsibility, didn't it? Please, do not project the last 2000+ yrs of exile. Check the historical record on what grew in Eretz Israel and what people had.

@AlBerko in fact it was imbalanced food, eating too much goat cheese, which is noted by the prophets that caused people get fat and forget Hashem.

@AlBerko Devarim 32:14, Isaiah 6:10, Jeremiah 5:28, Tehilim 17:10

I understand your way of thinking which is far from being critical. Once you're locked on an idea you will scrap any possible interpretation that in your eyes supports it. Critical thinking is about balancing your sources with those that might oppose your views. I'm very disappointed with the rabbinic tradition that leans toward confirmation bios rather than objectivity. If you observe Talmudic discourse you can see that each rabbi can present and defend only one position. So I suppose your goal is to justify yourself rather than find the truth.

Regarding Biblical verses. Rabbinic tradition does NOT rely on personal interpretation of the Torah unless there are rabbinic sources that discuss it. For me, by talking about Manna as having "nutritional value" you anachronize the Torah.

@AlBerko Manna was completely digested. No food is completely digested as the body does not need certain elements in the food. Stop being paleocritical. Rabbinic sources do not have a periodic table from chemistry.
